# Does the 1-loop beta function in $\phi^4$ theory depend on the renormalization scheme?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization

Consider Euclidean $\phi^4$ theory in $D=4$
$$
\mathcal{L}_0 = \frac{1}{2}\partial_{a}\phi_0\partial_{a}\phi_0 + \frac{1}{2}m_0^2\phi_0^2 + \frac{1}{4!}\lambda_0\phi_0^4
$$
The loop integrals are divergent so let's dimensionally regulate them, $D=4-\epsilon$. The four point amplitude $\Gamma^{(0)}_{4}(p_1, p_2, p_3, p_4)$ is a function of $\epsilon$. If we take the naive limit $\epsilon \to 0$ then the amplitude blows up. So we instead redefine fields and parameters for them to depend on $\epsilon$ in a way that renders the limit finite.
$$
\begin{aligned}
\phi_0 &= \tilde{Z}(m, \lambda, \epsilon; \mu)^{1/2} \ \phi \\
m_0 &= Z_{m}(m, \lambda, \epsilon; \mu) \ m^2 \\
\lambda_0 &= Z_{\lambda}(m, \lambda, \epsilon; \mu) \ \lambda \mu^\epsilon
\end{aligned}
$$
And rewrite the original lagrangian as
$$
\mathcal{L}_0 = \mathcal{L} + \mathcal{L}_{CT} \\
\mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2}\partial_{a}\phi\partial_{a}\phi + \frac{1}{2}m^2\phi^2 + \frac{1}{4!}\lambda\mu^\epsilon\phi^4 \\
\mathcal{L}_{CT} = \frac{1}{2}(\tilde{Z}-1)\partial_{a}\phi\partial_{a}\phi + \frac{1}{2}(\tilde{Z}Z_{m}-1)m^2\phi^2 + \frac{1}{4!}(\tilde{Z}^2 Z_{\lambda } - 1)\lambda\mu^{\epsilon}\phi^4 \\
$$
Since no renormalization is needed at tree level, we expect all $Z = 1 + \mathcal{O}(\lambda)$.

The 1-loop 4-point s-channel amplitude $\mathcal{A}(s)$ is
$$
\begin{align}
\mathcal{A}(s) &= \frac{(-\lambda \mu^{\epsilon})^2}{2} \int \frac{\text{d}^{4-\epsilon} k}{(2\pi)^{4-\epsilon}} \frac{1}{k^2 + m^2} \frac{1}{(k + p)^2 + m^2} \\
&= \frac{(-\lambda \mu^{\epsilon})^2}{2} \int_{0}^{1} \text{d}x \ \int \frac{\text{d}^{4-\epsilon} l}{(2\pi)^{4-\epsilon}} \frac{1}{(l^2 + m^2 + x(1-x)p^2)^2} \\
&= \frac{\lambda^2 \mu^\epsilon}{2 (4 \pi)^2} \int_{0}^{1} \text{d}x \left( \frac{m^2 + x(1-x)p^2}{4\pi \mu^2} \right)^{-\frac{\epsilon}{2}} \Gamma\left(\frac{\epsilon}{2}\right)
\end{align}
$$
This object has two interesting pieces, the $\mathcal{O}(\frac{1}{\epsilon})$ pole (coming from the Laurant expansion $\Gamma\left(\frac{\epsilon}{2}\right) = \frac{2}{\epsilon} - \gamma + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon)$), source of the initial divergence, to be cancelled by the $Z_\lambda$ counterterm. And the $\mathcal{O}(\epsilon^0)$ constant term, which gives the remaining amplitude as $\epsilon \to 0$.
The pole is
$$
\frac{\lambda^2}{(4\pi)^2\epsilon} \quad \implies \quad Z_{\lambda} = 1 + \frac{3\lambda}{(4\pi)^2\epsilon} + c_{\lambda} \lambda
$$
where $c_{\lambda}$ can be chosen to be anything finite as $\epsilon \to 0$. This also specifies the renormalization scheme. My understanding is that in the minimal subtraction (MS) scheme, $c_\lambda$ is set to $0$. But if we do keep a non-zero $c_\lambda$ to simplify the expression for the four point amplitude, which is now given by
$$
\mathcal{A}(s) = \frac{\lambda^2}{2(4\pi)^2} \left(-\gamma - \int_{0}^{1} \text{d}x \log \left( \frac{m^2 - x(1-x)s}{4\pi \mu^2} \right) \right)
$$
The integral can be easily done by parts and gives
$$
\mathcal{A}(s) = \frac{\lambda^2}{2(4\pi)^2} \left(-\gamma + 2 + \log \left( \frac{4\pi \mu^2}{m^2} \right) - 2\sqrt{1 - \frac{4m^2}{s}} \tanh^{-1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{4m^2}{s}}} \right)
$$
This suggests that it would be convenient to set
$$
c_\lambda = \frac{3}{2(4\pi)^2} \log \left( \frac{4\pi\mu^2 e^{2-\gamma}}{m^2} \right)
$$
The four-point function is now
$$
\Gamma_4 = -\lambda + \mathcal{A}(s) + \mathcal{A}(t) + \mathcal{A}(u) \\
\mathcal{A}(s) = -\frac{\lambda^2}{(4\pi)^2} \sqrt{1 - \frac{4m^2}{s}} \tanh^{-1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{4m^2}{s}}}
$$
This means
$$
\lambda_0 = \left( \lambda + \frac{3\lambda^2}{(4\pi)^2\epsilon} + \frac{3\lambda^2}{2(4\pi)^2} \log \left( \frac{4\pi\mu^2 e^{2-\gamma}}{m^2} \right) \right) \mu^{\epsilon}
$$
But this clearly does not lead to $\beta_\lambda = \mu \frac{d}{d\mu} \lambda(\mu) = \frac{3 \lambda^2}{(4\pi)^2}$
From what I've heard, the beta function doesn't depend on the renormalization scheme at one-loop. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It seems that if you take derivative of your last expression with respect to $\mu$ and take the $\epsilon \to 0$ limit, you can get your desired result $\beta=3\lambda^2/(4\pi)^2$ because the first and last term vanishes because of the $\epsilon$ dependence, only the second term survives. Or I didn't understand the question correct?

Comment: I thought so too but when I did this computation in Mathematica it turned out not to be the case because there's an explicit $\mu$ dependence in the last term. That part goes over the numerator without an $\epsilon$ factor and so survives $\epsilon \to 0$ limit. Of course there's an additional diagram giving the $\beta$ function for $m^2$ also here. So it's a coupled system of equations for $\beta_\lambda$ and $\beta_m$

Comment: From what I've understood, you can add whatever you want (finite in $\epsilon$) to the $Z$s as long as it's not explicitly dependent on $\mu$. As soon as I removed the $\mu^2$ in the log, I reproduce the correct answer. So, the best way is to just keep $\log \left( 4\pi e^{2-\gamma} \right)$ and retain a $\log \left( \frac{\mu^2}{m^2} \right)$ in the four point amplitude

Comment: The detailed form of $\beta$ is scheme-dependent, but its UV behaviour, which is you wanted to calculate, is scheme-independent. You can refer to [Notes on QFT](https://userswww.pd.infn.it/~feruglio/Serone.pdf) Chap 5.6 to see the detail.

Comment: So the result turns out to be that up to two loops, $\beta$ does not depend on the scheme. You can prove this very easily. But this assumes that $Z$ does not depend explicitly on $\mu$. I will write an answer soon. Thanks a lot for the notes! Seem useful